# Flex DataGridColumn with array of objects as data provider

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, arrays, object, datagridcolumn

I have a datagrid that uses an array of objects as the data provider.  The objects are essentially key/value pairs:
{ foo:"something"}
{ bar:"hello"}
{ caca:"lorem"}
The datagrid has 2 columns.  The first column is the key and the second column is the value.  Right now my grid looks like:

My dataFormatter function makes sure that depending on the column (i.e. the dataField value) the correct key or value gets printed out.  This works fine for displaying.  However, as soon as I try and edit the value field it essentially adds a new value into the object with a key of '1'.  For example, if I edit the {caca:"lorem"} object it will then contain the value {caca:"lorem",1:"new value"}.

Is there any possible way I can set the DataGridColumn so that when I edit a value it will update the value associated with the key rather than inserting a new value?  I've tried using a custom item editor but it still does the insert.  It seems like I need to be able to update the 'dataField' with the actual key value but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: var arr:Array = new Array();
//
//  setup key/value pair of objects
//
arr.push( {foo:"bar"} );
arr.push( {cat:"dog"} );
arr.push( {kick:"tothegroin"} );
var ac:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection( arr );
...
<mx:DataGrid dataprovider="{ac}">
   <mx:columns>
      <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="{should be key}" />
      <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="{should be value}"/>
   </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
p.s. I'm typing this off the top of my head.

Comment: wow, the above is not readable. is it possible to format code in a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to think about where your data is going to be stored. I would recommend listening for a CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE event on your data model. That event object will contain info about what change occurred, and you can make any updates you need to make.